# Assign a group of users to its own group Pod dynamically with Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes

I want to use Kubernetes to assign dynamic formed groups of learners/students to a specific "group" Pod/instance. The groups are formed in the learning management system Moodle. In the ongoing learning process, new groups are formed and old ones are removed. Is there a way to realise it and what is a "good way"? It is not yet clear to me.

Comment: What are learners?

Comment: You ca run multiple containers on the same pod,but it is still unclear to me what learners are.

Comment: I mean real users/students learning together in dynamic defined groups (per task) using the provided pod. The idea is that every group gets an own instance. The groups are defined outside of Kubernetes, here with the help of a learning management system.

Comment: So in an abstract view you can say that you dynamically provide each (external defined) group of users with its own instance of software.

Comment: You can use https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/